# How does function that isn't part of a class can be called from a class's function?

Tags: java, function, class, kotlin

I'm new in *Kotlin* (have some experience with Java). In *java*, each function (method) belong to class (static function or instance function). In *Java It* **isn't possible** to write a function outside a class .In *kotlin* i see that it is possible. I can't understand how, calling a function (that isn't part of a class scope) from a class function works.
Can someone explain me.
Code Example:
Class Wolf:

```
  class Wolf()
{
    var image = "wolf.jpg"
    var food = "meat"
    val habitat = "forests"

    fun makeNoise() {
        println("Hooooow!")
        addNumbers(5, 6)

    }
}
```

Method that isn't part of class:

```
   fun addNumbers (a:Int, b:Int): Int
 {
     return a+b
 }
```

Comment: That's just how kotlin works? Can you explain what you don't understand? -> Know that kotlin compiles to java bytecode where every function inside a file nests inside an auto-generated class

Comment: @Lino, i can't understand  many things: 1. does it acts like a static function of class? 2. When compiling, where does the function being store? Isn't it part of any class?  3. What is the scope of this function? can it be called from everywhere or only from the package?
I came from OOP knowledge so i really find it confusing

Comment: For 1 and 2: when you create a function `fun f() {}` inside a file `file.kt` then I assume that it will create something like this`class FileKt { public static void f() {} }`. For 3: When you have no modifier then it is *implicitly* `public`. Also note that `static` doesn't exist directly in kotlin, you either have functions in classes or just functions, where the former are similar to instance methods and the latter are similar to static methods

Comment: @Lino, the "latter" you have mentioned in your last sentence, it means that although it isn't directly called static, it acts and "feels" exactly as java static method but it doesn't belong to any Class?

Comment: It doesn't belong to a class in *Kotlin* but **does** in *Java*. Edit: just confirmed that it is exactly that way. for the before mentioned example the following bytecode is generated: `public final class FileKt { public static final f() {} }`

Comment: @Lino, Ok i'm confirming :) 10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope):

> In Kotlin functions can be declared at top level in a file, meaning you do not need to create a class to hold a function, which you are required to do in languages such as Java, C# or Scala. In addition to top level functions, Kotlin functions can also be declared local, as member functions and extension functions.

If you are wanting to know how this is implemented in JVM bytecode you can use the "Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode" then "Decompile" feature in IntelliJ.

You will see that if you put `addNumbers` in a `Wolf.kt` file, then the kotlin compiler generates the bytecode equivalent of:

```java
public final class WolfKt {
   public static final int addNumbers(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
   }
}
```

[You can control the name of the class with `@file:JvmName("WolfFunctions")`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions)

Comment: so if the *addNumbers* function being called from another class, when calling we need to call it like: WolfKt.addNumbers(5,6)? because i see that i can call it from every class that is in the package without the class name prefix

Comment: Yes. The kotlin compiler is generating the necessary byte code to make it work.

Comment: so i don't need the class name as a prefix when calling this method from a different file?